# Can GWT handle Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, gwt, jframe

I'm having some trouble building a GWT application.

Here: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/menu_editing Google themselves talk of the possibility of Java Swing, JFrame implementation in the GWT. I am a Java newbie and don't know what the SWT equivalent of Swing is, so I haven't tried that option.

When I try to run my code (which is built from the GWT Designer) I get errors at each line that uses JFrame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnNewMenu = new JMenu("Test");
        menuBar.add(mnNewMenu);

        JMenu mnNewMenu_1 = new JMenu("Test");
        mnNewMenu.add(mnNewMenu_1);
```

Returning: [ERROR] [gwtearthdemo] - Line 96: No source code is available for type javax.swing.JFrame; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Ditto for JMenuBar, JMenu.

I have seen errors similar to this with answers suggesting that the function in question is not applicable to GWT.  However, Google suggests it is.  Any advice here?

Comment: The [article cited](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/menu_editing) shows how the designer lets you choose widgets _comparable_ to those found in Swing or SWT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In GWT you are restricted to use only some of the java classes since it is not possible to convert all the java classes to javascript. You can find a list of the allowed classes in this link: [List of Classes](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation#Package_java_util)

Comment: Then I don't understand the link in my original question.  Why do they advertise it?

Comment: As a core gwt developer,i am less experienced with designer,have you added the source code of the swt and swing to the build path and tried along with the jars??

Comment: I thought swing was standard?  I don't know how to add it to the build path if it isn't already. 

Designer just produces lines of code for me, so it produced what is above.

Comment: I mean not only jars of SWT and Swing,I mean add the src(source code) jars also of the same.